# Scale Imageview nicely

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

The idea is to either display a photo or - if none is defined -  a small icon symbolizing it.

I have defined the following ImageView in the layout:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@+string/strImgPic"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:saveEnabled="false"
            android:src="@drawable/pic_icon" />
```

So the ImageView is pre-initialized with the 'icon' PNG.

The code to load it:

```
try {
imgURL = vinfo.getString("mainpic_url");
    if (imgURL.length() > 1) {
   imgURL = getString(R.string.urlPicsFull) + imgURL;
   ImageView imgPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPic);
   ImageDownloader img = new ImageDownloader();
   img.download(imgURL, imgPic);
    }
 } catch (..) {
(..)
```

ImageDownloader() basically does nothing else than retrieving the image asynchronously. The problem however is that if there  is NO image ( imgURL.length()==0 ) , the icon is displayed with a very large 'border' in the middle of an empty square in the layout.

I would like the image to be scaled down (or up) to the width of the parent view, but the icon to display as it is (about 90 dip wide and high).

Any suggestion on how to realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [android:scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) tag of the `ImageView`. For your case if you add

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

in your `ImageView` definition in the layout, and the image will be adjusted to your `ImageView` size. Something like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@+string/strImgPic"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        android:src="@drawable/pic_icon" />
```

However this will not maintain the aspect ratio so the image may be distorted. If you do not want that, check the other values that the `android:scaleType` tag can take in the link provided.